# Error 'Local = The function evaluation requires all threads to run' occurred in EF 6.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have been having issues debugging the code below which is an extension of ATM entity class.

```
  public static ATM GetAtmID(this ATM atm)
  {
     using (var cntx = new AtmDbContext())
     {
        var atms = cntx.Atms;  //Local = function requires all threads to run

        //this line throws an exception of 'Sequence contains no elements'
        var _atm = atms.Where(a => a.ip == atm.ip && a.isActive == true).AsEnumerable<ATM>().First(); 
        return _atm;
     }
  }
```

I have a table called atm ([atm table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fo3b.png)) in my database which has a record as shown below:

I tried to change the setting of the debugger in the Option menu, it wasn't resolved. Without the checkbox of the highlighted in the fig 2 as shown, by default, properties will not be evaluated. See the debugger property setting : [debugging property setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11FPx.png)

I wouldn't know if anybody could help me resolve this.

Thanks

Comment: What should exactly this extension method do for you?

Comment: Hey @Hakeen - a) Can you pastebin your records from atm table please. b) Provide the Model POCO for ATM c) Show us your Context implementation

Comment: @msd I used the extension to enhance separation of concern, to create methods for my model (entity class).

Comment: @garfbradaz, I have resolved the issue by using,   'System.Diagnostics.Debugger.NotifyOfCrossThreadDependency();'  within.

Comment: Not sure how the question title relates to your error... `Sequence contains no elements` is a message returned by `First` when you call it on an empty set. It means your Where clause found no matching records. You should either use `FirstOrDefault` or correct your `Where` predicate so that it always returns at least one record.

Comment: @Chris, the error of  _sequence contains no elements_ wasn't my initial problem but occurred as result of `var atms = cntx.Atms;` throwing _Local = function requires all threads to run_ as error. And  this has been resolved. Thanks